# Bash: Special variables $@ vs. $* in For Loop

Tags: bash, quoting, arguments, parameter

Using `$@`  instead of `$*` would preserve quoting. Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Test.sh
for arg in $@
do
echo "I found the argument $arg"
done

./Test.sh "One Two Three"
```

I reach the output below:

```
I found the argument One
I found the argument Two
I found the argument Three
```

I don't understand why the For loop is executed three times?!

Comment: The loop is executed several times because `$@` gets expanded, you should quote it then.